# Solve a system of non-linear eqations: $x\ln(x^2+y)+\frac{1}{x^2+y}=0$ and $y\ln(x^2+y)+\frac{2x}{x^2+y}=0$

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Solve a system of non-linear eqations:
$$x\ln(x^2+y)+\frac{1}{x^2+y}=0$$
$$y\ln(x^2+y)+\frac{2x}{x^2+y}=0$$

My idea was to write the first equation like so:
$$-x\ln(x^2+y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y}$$ and so from the second equation we would get:
$$y\ln(x^2+y)-2x^2\ln(x^2+y)=0$$
$$\ln(x^2+y)(y-2x^2)=0$$
which means that $x^2+y = 1$ or $2x^2=y$

but that would mean I can choose any 2 values for $x$ and $y$ as long as one of the two last equation is satisfied and that would be the solution, which is not true. 
Could anybody please explain me where my mistakes are or whether I've done something I shouldn't have done?

And also, how should I approach this problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you mean $x^2+y=1$ or $y=2x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If equations 1 and 2 are true, then equation 3 is true, but equation 3 might also be true when neither 1 nor 2 is.  So you can't just find all solutions to equation 3 and stop.

If $x^2+y=1$, you can use that to simplify equations 1 and 2.  That gives you one set of solutions.  If $y=2x^2$, equations 1 and 2 simplify in a different way, and that gives the other set of solutions.

Comment: Thank you. If I use the last equations to simplify the given equations, I would get $2$ equations with one variable for both solutions. By that i mean if I rewrite the given equations with the substitution for $y=2x^2$  I would get $2x^2\ln(3x^2)+\frac{2}{3x}=0$ and $x\ln(3x^2)+\frac{1}{3x^2}=0$, right? And now I would find the value for both $x$ so I could get 2 different values (for $x$), would that be correct? And I would do the same with the other equation $x^2+y=1$ which would lead to two different solutions again. So I could possibly get 4 sets of solutions, is that correct approach?

Comment: It turns out there is only one $x$ for the first case.  I don't think you can get an exact answer.  In the second case, note that $\ln(x^2+y)=\ln(1)=0$

Comment: Yeah, I've notised that. But I mean generally if I had some other given problem that would lead me to some 2 equation like here, whether I would get 4 equations for which $x$ could possibly have a different value? Or do I have to get 2 same values for $x$ from both equations in order for that to be the solution? Hope you understand my question.

Comment: When $y=2x^2$ the two equations 1 and 2 have become the same because equation 3 is zero.

Comment: Oh, right. I get it now, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(x^2+y)=-\frac{1}{x(x^2+y)}$$
$$\ln(x^2+y)=-\frac{2x}{y(x^2+y)}$$ so $$y=2x^2$$ substituting this we get
$$\ln(3x^2)+\frac{1}{3x^3}=0$$
$$\ln(3x^2)+\frac{1}{3x^3}=0$$
By a numerical method we get
$$x\approx -0.79974035684145550579$$